# Multi values for a field in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In this stored procedure, when `@Id` is 5, I want to get the records with Id's  3 and 5. How can I achieve that?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spEmployee
    @EmployeeName NVarchar(100),
    @Id int,
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT * 
    FROM tblEmployees 
    WHERE EmployeeName = CASE 
                            WHEN @EmployeeName IS NOT NULL
                               THEN @EmployeeName 
                               ELSE EmployeeName 
                         END
      AND Department = CASE 
                          WHEN @Id IS NOT NULL
                             THEN @Id 
                             ELSE Id 
                       END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select *
from tblEmployees
where (EmployeeName = @EmployeeName or @EmployeeName is null) and
      (@id is null or
       @id = 5 and Department = 3 or
       Department = @id
      );
```

In general, the use of `case` statements in the `where` clause makes the code a bit more difficult to follow (it is just another addition to the boolean operators).

Two good reasons for using a `case` in the `where` are:

- Because a column in the `select` uses the same logic.
- Because you need the sequential evaluation to prevent some sort of error or to ensure that an expensive function is rarely executed.

Otherwise, it is best to stick with `and` and `or`.

Comment: why I changed the code to  `@id = 5 and Id = 3 and Id = 2` it gives me just id=5

Comment: @E_N_Y . . . I don't know where the `id = 2` comes from.  Perhaps you mean `@id = 5 and Department in (2, 3)`.